# VBA Dynamic Userform Population Based on which Module Called It

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form where individuals can add details about tasks that populate a project planning table. If someone is creating a new task, all of the controls initialize with blank values. However, I want to create the ability for them to modify an existing task and along with it to populate the same user form's controls with the inputs that were originally submitted upon its initialization so they can tweak only what they need and not have to fill it out entirely.

I think there are several ways I could approach this, either by somehow passing variables from the EDIT TASK module to the userform or by potentially initializing the userform from the CREATE TASK and EDIT TASK modules themselves and populating the values of the controls from there like so

```
Sub Show_Insert_Task_Form()

INSERT_TASK_FORM.Show
INSERT_TASK_FORM.TASK_TBOX.value = "VALUE"

End Sub
```

This code runs, but it does not populate the textbox unfortunately.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Show_Insert_Task_Form` actually does populate the textbox.

From the behavior you are describing, I can deduce the `ShowModal` property (in the property window) of your form is `True`. When that is the case, VBA pauses the execution until you close the Window. In other words, what your code does is:

1. Show the form in modal mode.
   The textbox is not populated yet and as the form is modal, the execution is paused.
2. When you close the form, the execution resumes and the textbox gets populated (too late for you to see).

### Solution:

You must populate your form **before** calling `Show`.

```
Sub Show_Insert_Task_Form()
INSERT_TASK_FORM.TASK_TBOX.value = "VALUE"
INSERT_TASK_FORM.Show
End Sub
```

Doing so means the code will pause **after** the form is populated.

### About making the form non-modal:

The 2 changes below stop the execution from pausing:

1. Change the `ShowModal` property to `False` in the property window.
2. Call `INSERT_TASK_FORM.Show False`.

Both these alternatives are apparently a valid solution to your problem (without the execution pausing, the form gets populated while displayed on screen). However, they also make the bug prone to reappearing (example: if one day you change your mind and change the form back to being modal).

Good news is: the solution as well as these alternatives are not mutually exclusive. I recommend you implement the solution as well as alternative 1, alternative 2, or neither or both alternatives.